# java style enums in c++

Tags: c++, enums

In Java I can work with enums like classes. For example, I can create enum's constructor that take a value and init enum's value and class static function values() to list all enum's values.

How to impliment this in c++?

There is the java code:

```java
enum EquationType {

    LINE("LINE"), LINE3D("LINE3D"), BEZIER("BEZIER"), PLANE("PLANE");

    EquationType(String curve_type) {

        type = curve_type;

    } //END: CurveType()

    String type; // enum's member variable that store symbolic name of type (for utilite using)

    public String get_type_string() {

        return type;

    } //END: get_type_string()

    public static EquationType _bystring(String type) throws Exception {

        for (EquationType value : values()) { // search by list of enum's values

            if (value.get_type_string().equals(type.trim().toUpperCase())) {

                return value;

            }
        }

    } //END: _bystring()

} //END: enum EquationType
```

It creates enum with 4 members (LINE, LINE3D, BEZIER, PLANE). This enum class type have the function that return the enum's type by the string name value like EquationType._bystring("PLANE") will return EquationType.PLANE. It uses the values() function, that list all possible enum type values.

Is there some analog in c++?

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting?

Comment: I have my doubts as to whether that compiles in Java. Did you define a type called `string`?

Comment: There is no exact equivalent in C++, but there are several pretty close alternatives. In some cases an `enum class` will work. In this case, a full-fledged class, with some overloaded operators will probably be a closer match. In any case, unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a good C++ book, and you should find complete information about doing this in any good C++ book.

Comment: So you want to get the enum value via a string and vice versa? `std::unordered_map`? In this case maybe you don't want to use enum at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

enum EquationType {
  LINE, LINE3D, BEZIER, PLANE
};

int main() {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, EquationType> equationMap({
    {"LINE", LINE},
    {"LINE3D", LINE3D},
    {"BEZIER", BEZIER},
    {"PLANE", PLANE}
  });

  EquationType line = equationMap["LINE"];
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I haven't compiled this. I may have messed up the syntax.